# Image() or document.createElement('img')

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a difference between `new Image()` and `document.createElement(&#39;img&#39;)`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241716/is-there-a-difference-between-new-image-and-document-createelementimg)

What is the difference between creating image object with `Image` function and `createElement` function? Is there any?

```
var image1 = new Image;
var image2 = document.createElement('img');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Is there a difference between `new Image()` and `document.createElement('img')`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6241716/239241)

Answer (score 1):

The first construct an  image `object` (javascript image object).

The second create build an **img** html element `node`.

Comment: No, they create the same thing. `new Image()` is a relic from an older API ("DOM0").

Comment: @Tim Down: Wow. I did not really know it! :o