# Display Image that is in an Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I have a series of Arrays and as an output i want to display an image. I know how to do it using document.write but i cant get my head around how i would do something like this using the dom.

```
document.write("<p><img src='"+stones.value+"' alt='Mick'></p>");
```

How could i achieve something like this without using document.write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = stones.value;
 img.alt = 'Mick';

 document.getElementById('targetElement').appendChild(img);
```

I'm using the `Image` constructor here.

Oriol shows how to do it with pure DOM.

Nice read: [Is there a difference between `new Image()` and `document.createElement('img')`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241716/is-there-a-difference-between-new-image-and-document-createelementimg)

Answer (score 0):

Using DOM methods:

```
var p = document.createElement('p'),
    img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = stones.value;
img.alt = 'Mick';
p.appendChild(img);
wrapper.appendChild(p);
```

Using `innerHTML`:

```
wrapper.innerHTML += "<p><img src='"+stones.value+"' alt='Mick'></p>";
```

Where `wrapper` is a reference to the element where you want to insert that code. Some examples:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById(/* CSS id */);
var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName(/* CSS class */)[0];
var wrapper = document.querySelector(/* CSS selector */);
```

Comment: I hope i am not asking for too much but i cant seem to get this working. A fiddle with an example of an image being hidden and then displayed once a button is clicked would really help if its not too much trouble. Im having a hard time understanding this.

Comment: @user3538195 See this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2URjn/). But if the image is initially hidden, then see [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/2URjn/1/)