# Why is browser downloading an image even if tag is not inserted into DOM

Tags: javascript, html

If I do like that:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "2016-10-26_6-57-53.png";
```

Chrome sends a request to an image even before it's appended to the DOM.

It doesn't happen with the script:

```
var oScript = document.createElement("script");
oScript.src = "main.js";
```

Why the different behavior for the image?

Comment: `Image` is not a `HTMLElement` like `script`. `img` is and it will behave the same as script...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241716/is-there-a-difference-between-new-image-and-document-createelementimg

Comment: @marekful: `HTMLElement.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Image.prototype); // true`

Comment: You are right. Image is HTMLElement... Image is the older standard and it has event handlers for onload, onabort and onerror while createElement('img') does not. It was probably kept for convenience?

Comment: @marekful: I'm not sure what you're getting at. They both create the same kind of object. https://jsfiddle.net/7Lr27xdy/ In any case, the question is about the difference between an image and a script.

Comment: Only with an instance of `Image` you can listen for those events not with `createElement('img')`

Comment: @marekful: The jsfiddle I posted shows both responding to the `onload` event. They're the same kind of object, so they both exhibit the same behaviors.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#update-the-image-data https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#prepare-a-script

Comment: Basically the standard assumes that script can be not inserted and prefetch will be wasted but image probably will be inserted and should be prefetched even if not inserted.